# Modifiers in Solidity and access to values

Tags: solidity, modifier

What does the author mean by the following excerpt? Could anyone provide a good example?

> Inside a modifier, you can access all the values (variables and arguments) visible to the modified function. In this case, we can access the owner variable, which is declared within the contract. However, the inverse is not true: you cannot access any of the modifier’s variables inside the modified function.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a function is declared with the "view" scope, then the function can access global variables like "owner" as read only. The modifier can't write to "owner" though.

If the function is declared with "pure" scope, then the modifier can't access the global variable owner at all.

It boils down to modifiers can only be as or more restrictive than the functions they modify.

Also, modifiers can accept arguments, so you may pass arguments sent to the function on to the modifier as shown below.

```
contract token {
    uint owner;
    function foo(uint fooval) bar(fooval) view public{
    // this function is "view" so the modifier bar can only read owner at most
    // also, we can pass fooval on to the modifier

        uint infoo;
        infoo = owner;
    }

    modifier bar(uint barval) {
        uint hold;
        if (barval > 100) {
           // owner = 101; // not allowed, since foo is "view"
           hold = owner; // this is ok because foo is at least "view"
        }
        _;
    }
}
```